Cannot clip a GeoDataFrame that was clipped before from a different shapefile
I have a shapefile (~500 mb) that I read using geopandas. I clip it by country's boundary shapefile (which is done with no issues). Next I drop some columns from the result that are of no use, and select some data based on the time period I want. However, when I try to clip the file again with states boundary (same crs as geodataframe), it gives the error:
TypeError: 'gdf' should be GeoDataFrame or GeoSeries, got <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
The input to clip is a GeoDataFrame but it is not being clipped.
type(fire_file2024_proc2) Out: geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame
I have used these shapefiles previously so that is not an issue. I have provided a small sample of data (that was clipped from country's extent).
The entire code is somewhat like this:
# reading big, raw data
file1_raw = gpd.read_file("/home/ubuntu/file_raw.shp")
# reading outer shp
ind_shp = gpd.read_file("/home/ubuntu/ind_bdy.shp")

# first clip with country's extent
file1_proc1 = gpd.clip(file1_raw,ind_shp)
file1_proc2 = file_proc1.drop(['some unwanted columns'],axis=1)

# reading another big raw file
file2_raw = gpd.read_file("/home/ubuntu/file_raw2.shp")
# same process as above
# ------ #
# concat both files
file_proc2 = pd.concat([file1_proc2,file2_proc2])

# subset based on year
mask = (file_proc2['DATE_IST']>='2014-01-01) & (file_proc2['DATE_IST']<'2015-01-01')
file_proc2_2014 = file_proc2.loc(mask).reset_index(drop=True)

# reading states shapefile
ind_st = gpd.read_file("/home/ubuntu/ind_st.shp")

state_names = ind_st['Name'].to_list()
clipped_dfs_holder = []

# clipping all states
for i in range(len(state_names)):
    current_state = ind_st[ind_st['Name']==state_names[i]]
    df_st = gpd.clip(file_proc2_2014,current_state)
    clipped_dfs_holder.append(df_st)
    print("Clip complete for: "+state_names[i])


The code fails at line df_st = gpd.clip(file_proc2_2014,current_state). Thanks.

Not sure where your data sample files can be found?
Anyway, it is easier if the test data is just included in the test script, so I gave a try replacing your read commands with some inline test data, but I'm not able to reproduce your error.
Test script:
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely import box

# reading big, raw data
file1_raw = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data={"DATE_IST": [1, 2]}, geometry=[box(0, 0, 10, 10), box(50, 0, 60, 10)]
)
# reading outer shp
ind_shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[box(0, 0, 55, 55)])

# clip with country's extent
file1_proc1 = gpd.clip(file1_raw, ind_shp)
file1_proc2 = file1_proc1  # .drop(["some unwanted columns"], axis=1)

# reading another big raw file
file2_raw = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data={"DATE_IST": [1, 2]}, geometry=[box(0, 20, 10, 30), box(50, 50, 60, 60)]
)
# clip with country's extent
file2_proc1 = gpd.clip(file2_raw, ind_shp)
file2_proc2 = file2_proc1  # .drop(["some unwanted columns"], axis=1)
# concat both files
file_proc2 = pd.concat([file1_proc2, file2_proc2])

# subset based on year
mask = (file_proc2["DATE_IST"] > 0)
file_proc2_2014 = file_proc2.loc[mask].reset_index(drop=True)

# reading states shapefile
ind_st = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data={"Name": ["John", "Doe"]}, geometry=[box(0, 0, 2, 2), box(2, 2, 4, 4)]
)

state_names = ind_st["Name"].to_list()
clipped_dfs_holder = []

# clipping all states
for i in range(len(state_names)):
    current_state = ind_st[ind_st["Name"] == state_names[i]]
    df_st = gpd.clip(file_proc2_2014, current_state)
    clipped_dfs_holder.append(df_st)
    print("Clip complete for: " + state_names[i])
    print(df_st)


Thanks for the reply. The data can be found here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qh7rZueU0kg5S6tlWu-cyzLldXUcMQiH?usp=sharing. Please keep in mind this data is from Jan 2023 to Jun 2024 so the part of original code where a mask (though not used in your code) is made for 2014 would not work.

In general it is way more practical that the minimum data needed to reproduce a problem is included in the script to reproduce the problem, so ideally adapt your script like that, possibly starting from my script. If that wouldn't be possible, please make sure your script runs with the supplied data and shows the error clearly.

I just tried the code using the data I have provided above, the code works perfectly. However, what I have not mentioned is, I am using the ACQ_DATE and ACQ_TIME column to process the time information before second clipping by states.

I may try to clip first and then convert the date-time information. I suppose that way the error may not come. The function for conversion is here
